# Is there a nice, safe, quick way to write an InputStream to a File in Scala?

Tags: java, file, scala, inputstream, lift

Specifically, I'm saving a file upload to local file in a Lift web app.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If it's a text file, and you want to limit yourself to Scala and Java, then using `scala.io.Source` to do the reading is probably the fastest--it's not built in, but easy to write:

```
def inputToFile(is: java.io.InputStream, f: java.io.File) {
  val in = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(is)
  val out = new java.io.PrintWriter(f)
  try { in.getLines().foreach(out.println(_)) }
  finally { out.close }
}
```

But if you need other libraries anyway, you can make your life even easier by using them (as Michel illustrates).

(P.S.--in Scala 2.7, `getLines` should not have a `()` after it.)

(P.P.S.--in old versions of Scala, `getLines` did not remove the newline, so you need to `print` instead of `println`.)

Answer (score 41):

With Java 7 or later you can use `Files` [from the new File I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html):

```
Files.copy(from, to)
```

where `from` and `to` can be `Path`s or `InputStream`s. This way, you can even use it to conveniently extract resources from applications packed in a jar.

Comment: Do you need to call `close` after this?

Comment: `Files` itself does not represent a file, but is a static collection of I/O functions, so it does not require to be closed. `Files.copy` does not manipulate the streams you pass in, so whatever you may need to close there, you must close yourself.

Comment: can't call this method because of 
```
Error:(25, 11) overloaded method value copy with alternatives:
  (x$1: java.nio.file.Path,x$2: java.io.OutputStream)Long <and>
  (x$1: java.io.InputStream,x$2: java.nio.file.Path,x$3: java.nio.file.CopyOption*)Long <and>
  (x$1: java.nio.file.Path,x$2: java.nio.file.Path,x$3: java.nio.file.CopyOption*)java.nio.file.Path
 cannot be applied to (java.io.InputStream, java.io.File)
    Files.copy(content, distTemporaryFile)
```

Comment: It seems that you are passing an `File` as second argument whereas the functions expects a `Path`. You could `File.toPath()` to obtain the `Path`.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know about any Scala specific API, but since Scala is fully compatible to Java you can use any other library like [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) and [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).

Here is some example code (untested):

```
//using Commons IO:
val is = ... //input stream you want to write to a file
val os = new FileOutputStream("out.txt")
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, os)
os.close()

//using Commons FileUpload
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.{FileItemFactory, FileItem}
import apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload
val request: HttpServletRequest = ... //your HTTP request
val factory: FileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory()
val upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory)
val items = upload.parseRequest(request).asInstanceOf[java.util.List[FileItem]]
for (item <- items) item.write(new File(item.getName))
```

Answer (score 4):

The inputToFile method given above doesn't work well with binary files like .pdf files. It throws a runtime exception while attempting to decode the file into string. What worked for me was this:

```
def inputStreamToFile(inputStream: java.io.InputStream, file: java.io.File) = {
    val fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(file)
    fos.write(
      Stream.continually(inputStream.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
    )
    fos.close()
}
```